# FullCalendar not displaying datetime

Tags: javascript, node.js, fullcalendar, sails.js

Attempting to use FullCalendar v3.9.0 with SailsJS. Using jQuery v3.2.1. MomentJS and jQuery are loaded before fullcalendar. This is my current code for FullCalendar.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'today prev,next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  views: {
    week: {
      titleFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
    }
  },
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  locale: 'fi',
  weekends: true,
  events: [
    {
      title: 'Event 1',
      start: '2018-06-25T15:00+03:00'
    },
    {
      title: 'Event 2',
      start: '2018-06-26T12:00+03:00'
    }
  ],
  editable: true,
  selectable: true,
});
```

However, the outcome looks like this.
[image: https://i.imgur.com/AIm5k9n.png]

The datetime of each row is missing. Also the buttons on both sides of title are missing.

Comment: its loading proper. see https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/eKPBaG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot you appear to be using the print CSS provided by FullCalendar instead of the browser CSS.

If you have included both files, make sure you set the media query correctly on the print.css file so it is only used when printing the page. For example:

```
<link href='fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
```

Ensure that `media='print'` is present on the "print" file, as per the above example.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link for the syntax, and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries for information about media queries in general.

Comment: This appears to have been the issue. I removed the print css entirely and now it's working as supposed. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. No need to remove it entirely though - it's useful if someone does want to print the page, as it provides a more printer-friendly set of colours etc.